# app is crashing after few seconds in debugging mode but it's working fine if i run the app normally

Tags: android, kotlin, debugging

I have build very simple app

[here's my MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46t6j.png)

its working fine when i run it in my phone using usb cable, but when i run it using `debug app` it crashes after fews seconds why is this happening

*this is what i'm getting in logcat after crash*

```
ANR in com.project.debugapp
PID: 7376
Reason: Changing to new focus window timeout
ErrorId: 4d4000b3-10fc-465a-a960-b03eb40b52fb
Frozen: false
Load: 0.0 / 0.0 / 0.0
\----- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
some avg10=0.18 avg60=0.08 avg300=0.06 total=218376347
full avg10=0.00 avg60=0.00 avg300=0.00 total=65300731
\----- End output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
```

i have tried to run app in debugging mode in several android phones but it crashes everytime.

Answer (score 0):

It just ANR(Application not Responding) log, it usually occurs when you are in debug mode, you can ignore this or if you don't what this ANR dialog to popup during Debug mode, you can select your app as debug app in Developer settings.

Note: Developer option may available under different section based on manufacturer.

Settings -> System -> Developer options -> Select debug app -> (Select the app which you are working with)